# Can I set a different path for a child dependency in the require.config?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs

I have two problems that are related to each other.

The first is that I want to have a folder named backbone, and that collides with having backbone as a short name for the library in the path. It seems that RequireJS thinks that backbone/model/User is a child of the backbone library or something. Solution, name the library Backbone with capital B.

The second problem is that I'm using ModelBinder, which has "backbone" as a dependency. Solution, change the minified file.

Both solutions seems like a bad hack for not doing something right in RequireJS configuration, but I cant figure out what I'm doing wrong.

My public folder structure is something like:

```
public/
  js/
    backbone/
      model/
        ...
      view/
        ...
    vendor/
      backbone.min.js
      Backbone.ModelBinder.js
      ...
  common.js
```

My common.js has something like this:

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: "/js",
    shim: {
        'underscore': {
            exports: '_'
        },
        "Backbone" : {
            deps: ["underscore", "jquery"],
            exports: 'Backbone'
        }

    },
    paths: {
        underscore: 'vendor/underscore.min',
        jquery: 'vendor/jquery',
        model_binder: 'vendor/Backbone.ModelBinder',
        Backbone: 'vendor/backbone.min'
  }
});
```

So my two questions are: How can I keep Backbone.ModelBinder as it is, and tell requirejs that when that library ask for backbone, its asking for js/vendor/backbone.min.js without "polluting" my global paths.

And why can't I use both backbone (lowercase b) in the path and have the directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution (yes, not so sane) is to include `paths` definitions for every directory under `js/backbone`, i.e.:

```
require.config({
    ...
    paths: {
        ...
        backbone: 'vendor/backbone.min', // NOTE lower-case 'b', as desired
        "backbone/model": "backbone/model",
        "backbone/view": "backbone/view",
        ... // and so on
    }
});
```

This also means that there is no module directly under `js/backbone`.

An alternative would be to keep the capital 'B' in the module name for Backbone and use the `map` config for the `Backbone.ModelBinder.js`:

```
require.config({
    ...
    paths: {
        ...
        Backbone: 'vendor/backbone.min' // NOTE capital 'B' again
    },
    map: {
        "model_binder": {
            "backbone": "Backbone"
        }
});
```

---

Thinkng retrospectively, the `map` can be applied to *all modules* so that whenever they request `"backbone"` (lower-case 'b') you deliver `"Backbone"`:

```
require.config({
    ...
    paths: {
        ...
        Backbone: 'vendor/backbone.min' // NOTE capital 'B' again
    },
    map: {
        "*": {    //  <------ Here difference form code above
            "backbone": "Backbone"
        }
});
```

Now anyone can ask for `"backbone"` and get Backbone, or `"backbone/model/User"` (or `"backbone/module"`) and get the corresponding module.

Comment: I used the first approach and it works, but it seems like a bug. If I dont have this defined: 'backbone/views': 'backbone/views, I get the error /js/vendor/backbone.min/views/MyView.js 404 (Not Found).